# Estimate search result | Gmail API PHP

Tags: php, api, gmail, google-api-php-client, gmail-api

I am trying to get the number of emails (read & unread shown separately) for a given search. I've read that the labels.get() function does the trick but I don't know how to use it. Here's the code I have to detect if I have less or more than 100 result for a given sender.

```
      require_once '../../vendor/autoload.php';
      session_start();
      $client = new Google_Client();
      $client->setAuthConfigFile('../../client_secrets.json');
      $client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY);
      $client->addScope(Google_Service_Gmail::GMAIL_READONLY);
      $client->setAccessType("offline");
      $client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
      $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
      $service = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);

      $sender = array();
      $sender[] = 'sender1@email.com';
      $sender[] = 'sender2@email.com';
      $sender[] = 'sender3@email.com';

      function countfrom($service, $userId, $expeditor) {
            try
            {
              unset($optParamsamz);
              $optParamsamz = [];
              $optParamsamz['maxResults'] = 100; // Return Only 5 Messages
              $optParamsamz['q'] = "From: '".$expeditor."'  "; 
              $messagesamz = $service->users_messages->listUsersMessages('me',$optParamsamz);
              $listamz = $messagesamz->getMessages();
              echo sizeof($listamz);

          }
         catch (Exception $e)
            {
              print 'An error occurred: ' . $e->getMessage();
            }

          }

foreach ($sender as $key => $value)
            {
             echo $value .': ';
             countfrom($service,$_SESSION['emaile'],$value)  ;
             echo '<br/>';
            }
```

------------------- EDIT ----------------------

I have tried a new solution that seems closer to what I'm looking for. The issue now comes from Google who returns some odd number for the resultestimatsize:

```
<?
  require_once '../../vendor/autoload.php';
  session_start();
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setAuthConfigFile('../../client_secrets.json');
  $client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY);
  $client->addScope(Google_Service_Gmail::GMAIL_READONLY);
  $client->setAccessType("offline");
  $client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
  $service = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);

  $sender_array[] = 'sender1@sender.com';
  $sender_array[] = 'sender2@sender.com';
  $sender_array[] = 'sender3@sender.com';
  $sender_array[] = 'sender4@sender.com';

  foreach ($sender_array as $key => $expeditor)
  {

    $optParamsamz1['q'] = "From: '".$expeditor."' is:read  "; 
    $optParamsamz2['q'] = "From: '".$expeditor."'   "; 

    echo $expeditor.": ".$service->users_messages->listUsersMessages('me',$optParamsamz1)->getResultSizeEstimate() . "
                       ".$service->users_messages->listUsersMessages('me',$optParamsamz2)->getResultSizeEstimate(); 
    echo "<br>";
  }
```

?>

Comment: Just to clarify :) Do you want to get every mail from a particular email, or do you just want the number of read/unread email?

Comment: I'd like to be able to have x read / y unread  emails for a search like 'From: sender1@gmail.com'

Answer (score 1):

`labels.get()` will be of no help in this use case, I'm afraid. It only works for labels, so you could get read/unread from e.g. `INBOX` or `CHAT` easily, but will be of no help if you want to get all read/unread from e.g. all messages sent from `example@gmail.com`.

An alternative solution is fairly cheap though:

1. List messages with the query + `AND is:unread`, and a second one with the same query +
   `AND -is:unread`.
2. If the response contains a `nextPageToken`, you have 100+ read/unread. If it does not contain a `nextPageToken`, there are `response.messages.length` amount of read/unread messages.

**Example**

**Request unread**

```
q = from:info@berniesanders.com AND is:unread

GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?q=from%3Ainfo%40berniesanders.com+AND+is%3Aunread&access_token={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

**Response**

```
{
 "messages": [
  {
   "id": "1523144d6e3feb2e",
   "threadId": "1523144d6e3feb2e"
  },
  {
   "id": "15227d879ccb601f",
   "threadId": "15227d879ccb601f"
  }, ...
}
// No nextPageToken => response.messages.length unread = 22 unread
```

**Request NOT unread**

```
q = from:info@berniesanders.com AND -is:unread

GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?q=from%3Ainfo%40berniesanders.com+AND+-is%3Aunread&access_token={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

**Response**

```
{
 "messages": [
  {
   "id": "1522d4af39d7eec6",
   "threadId": "1522d4af39d7eec6"
  },
  {
   "id": "1521d6f3dbeaf886",
   "threadId": "1521d6f3dbeaf886"
  }, ...
  "nextPageToken": "32436546446"
}
// nextPageToken in response => 100+ read
```

You could take it one step further and keep on listing with the `nextPageToken` until there is no `nextPageToken` in the response, and just add all the results together, but that might be to slow or inefficient for your use case.

Comment: Thanks, that' ll do the trick. Fyi I'll go for a solution that takes the 100 first emails as a sample and run the unread/read calculation on it.

Comment: Actually there's a EstimateSearch Result given by Gmail but the number seems odd to me (always something like 103 !) . The function I use is : getResultSizeEstimate that retrieve the value resultSizeEstimate

Comment: @justberare You're right. I didn't know that! It estimated my entire inbox of ~7500 messages to 308 though, so I don't really trust it. Maybe I'm misunderstanding how it should work.

Comment: thanks for your comment, it feels good not to be alone with a bug. Can't figure out what the solution is though

Comment: Same issue. Always 103 messages as estimate.